# NSManagedObjectContext's Save method performance

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, save, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm optimising my first iOS app before it hits the store, and noting methods which take seemingly larger amounts of time. I have a fairly simple master-detail app where entities from the Core Data SQLite are shown in a `UITableView`, then tapping one brings up a detail view where the user can mark it as a favorite (setting a `BOOL` flag in that object to `YES`. As soon as they hit their Favorite button, I call `[NSManagedObjectContext save]` to ensure their changes are reflected immediately, and in case of an unscheduled terminate, etc.

This `save` operation is currently taking around 205ms when testing on my iPhone 4S. There are around 4,500 entries in the database, each with a few strings, and a few boolean values (wrapped in `NSNumber`s).

First question: **should it take 200ms to make this change?** I'm only setting one boolean value, then saving the context, but I've never used Core Data before so I don't know if this is about normal.

Second question: **the code I'm using is below – am I doing something wrong in the code to make the method take this long to execute?**

```
- (IBAction) makeFavorite: (id) sender
{
    [self.delegate detailViewControllerDidMakeFavorite];
    [_selectedLine setIsLiked: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];
    [_selectedLine setIsDisliked: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]];
    NSError *error;
    if (![[[CDManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext] save:&error]) NSLog(@"Saving changes failed: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

Perhaps I'm worrying over nothing (I am still a relatively new programmer), but on a wider note, 200ms is enough for me to at least try to address this issue, right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `UIManagedDocument`.  It automatically handles saving in a background context.  I especially recommend it if you are on iOS 6.  If you are not passing object IDs around, or merging with other contexts, then you should be able to use it fairly easily and reliably.

Your simple use case seems tailor made for it.

Comment: I looked around for tutorials on the subject but found basically nothing, it seems that it's primarily designed for iCloud, which I'm not using. It looks like it's for creating a document, but I'm just pulling a single entity out of a Core Data SQLite database, I don't have any document per se. I'm not sure how it ties into what I'm doing at all, I'm afraid.

Comment: UIManagedDocument is not just for iCloud.  It provides a "prebuilt" core data stack: main MOC with a private MOC parent running on a background thread.

Comment: I have no idea what an MOC is, that comment was way above my head. I've not been able to find any documentation or tutorials for it that aren't hideously confusing – would it require re-writing all of my Core Data code to implement it?

Comment: Sorry, MOC is shorthand for ManagedObjectContext.  Like any programming, if you designed you code in a good, modular fashion, then the change should be minimal.  If you just wrote it in-place, then it will require some change... how much depends on how you wrote it.  My best suggestion at this point is to get the new edition of Marcus' book at Pragmatic Programmers.  It is a good tutorial of Core Data basics.

Comment: My integration with CoreData is almost exclusively confined to just performing fetches, and shoving the results into a tableView. I'm also editing some values (such as the one in the question). Is this likely to require complete tear-down of my project?

Comment: Only you can determine what is right for your project.  But, if you want to get rid of the lags you were talking about, then you must offload the saving into a background context.  There are several ways to do that.  You can use a separate private MOC as a parent, but it requires some intimate knowledge of core data... or you can use UIManagedDocument, which is an easier API to use.  Your choice.  Use nested MOCs, UIManagedDocument, something else, or just live with it.

Answer (score 0):

> > 1) Should the save of one change of boolean value take 200 ms?

Yes, it might take this long. You are performing an IO operation and according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html):

> > When Core Data saves a SQLite store, SQLite updates just part of the store file. Loss of that partial update would be catastrophic, so you may want to ensure that the file is written correctly before your application continues. Unfortunately, doing so means that in some situations saving even a small set of changes to an SQLite store can take considerably longer than saving to, say, an XML store.

-

> > 2) am I doing something wrong in the code to make the method take this long to execute?

No. you are making the save to the store (under the assumption you have no parent context).

-

> > 3) Are 200ms enough for me to at least try to address this issue?

Yes. 200ms are a noticeable time for a human, and will be felt. you could try and perform the save in the background, but this is unsafe according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW7). or, move it to the end of the entire object editing.

My advise would be to read and see if you could make some compromises in your context architecture (your CoreData stack structure).
From my experience, saving in the background is not that bad.